# Anyone using RavenDB in a production environment?

Tags: production-environment, ravendb, document-oriented-db

I'm doing research on the maturity of some document-oriented stores, which includes an overview of applications and websites that use the database in production environments. There are several lists and case studies available for CouchDB and MongoDB, including:

- [CouchDB In The Wild](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CouchDB_in_the_wild)
- [MongoDB Production Deployments](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments)

I'm having a hard time finding applications and websites that use **RavenDB in production**. Does anyone have first-hand experience with this, or examples of (well-known) sites that run on RavenDB?

Comment: Same here - researched into CouchDB, MongoDB, Cassandra + others, but struggled to find production users for RavenDB

Comment: Well RavenDB is so young, there wont be to many applications out there using it.

Comment: @Gamlor: I didn't realize it was officially released only three months ago. I've read about it and I've seen it being compared to CouchDB, so I suppose it has a lot of potential. Perhaps early adopters have already put it to good use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several people in the process of deploying RavenDB, see the discussion thread [here](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/af6343035024f600) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

A testimonial called [Case Study: The First RavenDB Deployment](http://ravendb.net/testimonials/first) was posted on the RavenDB site last month. Ayende's [post on this case study](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/03/30/case-study-the-first-ravendbrsquos-production-deployment-story.aspx) features a comment of the interviewee, explaining a bit more on his decision-making.

Answer (score 2):

We're about to pop a beta of http://sonatribe.com which uses ravendb extensivley

The developer experience is great and the support is the same.